# Showing October 2020 as Oct 2020 on the X axis of PowerBI Chart

Tags: powerbi

I have a PowerBI Chart that I am working on for which. I got the Bars Chart on the X axis and the value for each bar  in the chart is Month and Year. It is showing full months name like October 2020 but my business user wants to see OCT 2020 instead of October 2020.

[image]

Please help me how to change it

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Go to Transform data and add a column to your table with the following formula

```
your_new_shortname = Format (Table[Date], "mmm")
```

Use this new column in your visualization.

Answer (score 0):

Add a calculated column on your date table and set its [Sort By Column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-sort-by-column#sort-using-the-sort-by-column-button).